# Insert elements on AVL Tree

Tags: c, tree, avl-tree

A professor claims that the order in which a fixed set of elements is inserted into an AVL tree does not matter—the same AVL tree results every time.

Give a small example that proves that the professor is wrong.

Comment: How about trying by yourself first with, say, [AVL Tree Visualzation](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html)?

Comment: Thank you I think I understood @MikeCAT, so the bellow answer is right ?

Answer (score 1):

As a trivial example consider the set with elements 1 & 2. Insert 1 then 2 and the root is 1 with 2 as a right child. Insert 2 then 1 and the root is 2 with 1 as the left child.

You will get an AVL tree every time but elements can be in different locations based on the order they were inserted.

Correct me if im wrong

Comment: Thank you, I will wait for a more complete answer, and someone to verify that its right.